# Unit Test - sometimes works, sometimes not

Tags: c#, double, mstest

I have a unit test below running against the code that follows. This test sometimes passes, sometimes fails. Not sure why and hesitate to change things radically since well, it is a formula and sometimes passes...I'm thinking it may have something to do with the precision of the type double? Not sure. Thoughts?

[image: Good test]

[image: Bad test]

```
[TestMethod]
public void CircleFromCircumference()
{
    var random = new Random();
    var circumference = random.NextDouble();
    var circle = new Circle("My circle", circumference, Circle.CircleDimensions.Circumference);

    var var1 = circumference - circle.Circumference;
    var var2 = circumference - 2 * Math.PI * circle.Radius;
    var var3 = circumference - Math.PI * circle.Diameter;
    var var4 = Math.Pow(circumference / (2 * Math.PI), 2) * Math.PI - circle.Area;

    Assert.IsTrue(
        circumference - circle.Circumference <= 0 //circumference
        && circumference - 2 * Math.PI * circle.Radius <= 0 //radius
        && circumference - Math.PI * circle.Diameter <= 0 //diameter
        && Math.Pow(circumference / (2 * Math.PI), 2) * Math.PI - circle.Area <= 0 //area
        && string.IsNullOrEmpty(circle.ShapeException));
}



using System;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;

namespace Shapes
{
    [DataContract]
    public class Circle : Shape
    {
        [DataMember] public double Radius { get; set; }
        [DataMember] public double Diameter { get; set; }
        [DataMember] public double Circumference { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// The name of the value you are sending. Radius is the default
        /// </summary>
        public enum CircleDimensions
        {
            Circumference = 1,
            Area = 2,
            Diameter = 3
        }
        /// <summary>
        /// 
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="circleName">The name of your circle</param>
        /// <param name="dimension">The value of the dimension you are providing</param>
        /// <param name="circleDimensions">The name of the value you are providing. Radius is default</param>
        public Circle(string circleName, double dimension = 0, CircleDimensions circleDimensions = 0)
        {
            this.ShapeName = circleName;
            if (dimension <= 0)
            {
                this.ShapeException = "Parameters must be greater than zero";
                return;
            }

            switch (circleDimensions)
            {
                case CircleDimensions.Circumference:
                    //radius from Circumference
                    this.Circumference = dimension;
                    this.Radius = this.RadiusFromCircumference(dimension);
                    this.Area = this.CalculateArea(this.Radius);
                    this.Diameter = this.CalculateDiameter(this.Radius);
                    break;
                case CircleDimensions.Area:
                    //radius from Area
                    break;
                case CircleDimensions.Diameter:
                    //radius from diameter
                    break;
                default: //calculate from radius
                    this.Radius = dimension;
                    this.Diameter = this.CalculateDiameter(dimension);
                    this.Circumference = this.CalculateCircumference(dimension);
                    this.Area = this.CalculateArea(dimension);
                    break;
            }
        }

        private double RadiusFromCircumference(double dimension) => dimension / (2 * Math.PI);

        private double CalculateCircumference(double dimension) => 2 * Math.PI * dimension;
        private double CalculateDiameter(double dimension) => 2 * dimension;
        private double CalculateArea(double dimension) =>
            Math.PI * (Math.Pow(dimension, 2));
    }
}
```

Comment: That's a LOT of && conditions in your assert. I would consider asserting each of those individually, and working out which one is flakey.

Comment: Unseeded random in a unit-test. Thats probably not a good idea...

Comment: Sure, that's why I have the var1-4, it is always var2, var3 that have unexpected values. @Alex

Comment: you have `var 1 = ` etc.. but then don't do anything with the variable.

Comment: @Alex, code is in flux, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The inconsistency has nothing to do with precision per se, it has more to do with how floating point representation works. For example, if you write this:

```
for (float f = 0.0f; f != 1.0f; f+=0.1f)
{
   Console.WriteLine(f);
}
```

It will never exit. Because 0.1 does not have an exact representation in binary form. (https://www.exploringbinary.com/why-0-point-1-does-not-exist-in-floating-point/). I also recommend reading (https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)

Back to the problem at hand, in your code, you are getting the Radius using this :

```
dimension / (2 * Math.PI); //passed in dimension is the Circumference, returns radius
```

And then in your test you are asserting that:

```
circumference - 2 * Math.PI * circle.Radius <= 0
```

Dividing and then multiplying by the same floating point number is not guaranteed to give you the original floating point number as a result.

Thus, it is a bad idea in general to assert this. The most common way to test "almost equality" is to test equality "within limits". In your case, all you have to do is define a small enough epsilon that you deem "acceptable", greater or equal to double.Epsilon in your tests.

```
var epsilon = double.Epsilon;
Assert.IsTrue(
    Math.Abs(circumference - circle.Circumference) <= epsilon //circumference
    && Math.Abs(circumference - 2 * Math.PI * circle.Radius) <= epsilon //radius
    && Math.Abs(circumference - Math.PI * circle.Diameter) <= epsilon //diameter
    && Math.Abs(Math.Pow(circumference / (2 * Math.PI), 2) * Math.PI - circle.Area) <= epsilon //area
    && string.IsNullOrEmpty(circle.ShapeException));
```

If instead you have to guarantee exactness, one option is to switch to a non-floating point type like decimal, but expect a performance hit.

Comment: Use of double.Epsilon did the trick. Any concerns with changing the unit test to make it pass, rather than the program code? @Alexandru

Comment: Actually, this is fool proof either :(

Comment: Use of Assert.AreEqual reveals this: Assert.AreEqual failed. Expected:<0.985622078173618>. Actual:<0.985622078173618>

Comment: @Steve With floating point math you never get 100% :))) As I said, double.Epsilon is the smallest epsilon you can use, you can always use 2*eps or 10*eps. It will take some tweaking and thinking. It really depends on the type of caculation and on what you really want to test. As others suggested, you might want to steer clear of Random. Right now you are testing ‘reversed’ formulas of the actual classes. The idea of unit tests is to find (by hand) cases that are interesting or might fail. Testing the limits of floating point arithmetic may not be the best thing to do(testing reversed formulas)

Comment: @Steve most likely those numbers are not equal, debug the test to see more digits. I cannot tell you a 100% answer on how to test because I lack context, I was merely pointing out your expectation vs reality. I have no idea what you are building and what the implications of decisions are. That is your baby :)) It is up to each of us as programmers to be aware of limitations of our hardware and software and find creative ways to use them or work around them to achieve our goals.

Comment: @Steve Hmmm, I did not know: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms243458. apparently the delta logic is also provided in assert.areequal